# Can connectedCallback() in a Custom Component be interpreted in different ways, depending on the context where it is used?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, custom-component

I created a Custom Component which includes a Vue instance:

```js
class ContentCardExample extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.setAttribute("id", "app")
    card.innerHTML = 'hello is {{hello}}'
    this.appendChild(card);
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        hello: 5
      }
    })
  }
}

customElements.define('content-card-example', ContentCardExample);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<content-card-example></content-card-example>
```

It works fine **standalone** (that is - used as in the snippet above directly in a browser)

I then tried to add it to [Home Assistant](https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/en/lovelace_custom_card.html) which provides a way to create customized cards by creating a Custom Element which is then displayed by Home Assistant.

Using the same code in Home Assistant results in a Vue warning (effectively - an error): `Cannot find element #app`

My question is the following: **are there circumstances where the my Custom Component is rendered differently depending on where it is used?**. The collateral question is "if yes - is this normal and expected"

Note: **I do not want to make this a "Home Assistant" question** (this is not the right place to ask it) - but rather to understand if what I wrote can be considered "self contained" and once it works in a simple HTML file it should work anywhere - or whether an Custom Element **content** still relies / is dependent on where this element is used. Home Assistant happens to be a place where this difference in behaviour happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vue Instance cannot find `#app`. You can pass your `card` element directly to `el`. I used a variable called `vm` to call the vue instance later and append it to your DOM with `vm.$el`.

Try this:

```
class ContentCardExample extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const card = document.createElement('div');

    card.innerHTML = 'hello is {{hello}}';

    const vm = new Vue({
      el: card,
      data: {
        hello: 5
      }
    });

    this.appendChild(vm.$el);
  }
}

customElements.define('content-card-example', ContentCardExample);
```

Comment: Thank you - your solution works perfectly. Would you know how to address the Vue instance from outside `connectedCallback()`? Specifically: I will use a setter for a variable and would like to update there `hello` in the Vue instance.

Comment: Nice to hear ;) If you want to edit the value of `hello` outside, you can add `vm` globally and call `$data.hello = 10`, `Vue.set(vm, 'hello', 10)` or `vm.$set(vm, 'hello', 10)
`. You can also add `vm` as instance variable and add your own class methods to update your data.

Comment: Thanks. I created a property `this.vm` in the constructor and assigned it  `this.vm = vm` in `connectedCallback()`. I then updated the value via `this.vm.hello = hass` in the setter for `hass`. Works great, thanks again. (I would be curious to understand why `#app` was not found (it was OK in the standalone file) but the important part is that everything works great now)